# Test a value contained in the cell of a TableView against an array

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, custom-cell

I need to test if the value of a custom cell label is contained within an array. To achieve this I created a function that does the test and returns a boolean. My problem is that every time the cell enters the screen, the test is done again.
Where should I make the test so it is done only once ?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTableViewCell
    var name:String = Array(self.contactList[indexPath.row].keys)[0]
    var phones:String = self.contactList[indexPath.row]["\(name)"]!
    cell.nameLabel.text = name
    cell.phoneLabel.text = phones
    cell.inviteButton.tag = indexPath.row

    var (matched, id) = self.isRegistered(phones)
    if(matched){
        cell.phoneLabel.text = "TRUE"
        cell.idUser = "\(id)"
    }

    return cell
}
```

I need to be able to modify the cell in response to this test. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is called every time the cell appears because you a placed the test call inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (If like you said you need to change the cell's label value according to the test result, I don't see any other choice)

You can try using the UITableViewDelegate methods

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

This will be called every time a cell needs to be presented.

Second way is a bit tricky and I don't recommend it, you can create a `pool` (array) of `UITableViewCell`s and maintain (call test & change values) from that pool at a time you think is best (when scrolling the `tableView` for example)

Comment: Isn't it a waste of ressources to trigger the function every time the cell is displayed when only one is sufficient ? As a web developer, I'm having quite a difficult time trying to understand the logic behind this..

Comment: you are correct but, 1) the fact is you never know when your database may change. 2) the cells that are referenced in your method are reused, so you might have values in them that are not in the right place. If your method was a call to the web i would advise you not to call it there, but you are configuring the cell, and that is the place for it.

Comment: So I'll let my test where I put it in the first place. Thanks for the explanation !

Comment: Me again.... In my test, I check if the value of my cell's texfield (phonenumber from addressbook) is contained in an array of users that I fetch from my web API. If there's a match, I display a button in my cell to allow friend request. So when someone presses the button, I need to add the id of the corresponding user of my API array to another array that I will send in a POST request at the end, to actually make the friend requests. But I can't figure out how to get this id from the cell in my IBAction. Any ideas ?

Comment: you can use the 'tag' property in a UIView subclass, it is a NSInteger. A UIButton is a UIView subclass so yo can add to the 'yourButton.tag' the user id.

Comment: I tried this technique to keep reference of the `indexPath.row` but as my 2 arrays are not the same size, it didn't work. I didn't even think to put the id in the tag directly ! Thanks for your help !